# Relative div with no height holding absolute elements. Is it good practice?

Tags: css

I couldn't really come up with a title to describe my potential issue. I have built a datepicker plugin that works fine in browsers I tested. But there's just this thing that bugs me that I need a few words of comfort about. It is a regular input field that when clicked on a window pops over it allowing you to choose the date and stuff, this is how I've accomplished the "popping up" part

### HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='title'>
        Choose date
        <span class='close'>X</span>
    </div>
    <div class='window'> ... </div>
</div>
<input class='datepicker'>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper { position:relative; }
.title { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0 }
.window { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

So it seems like a valid structure and as `wrapper` is before the input field I'm guaranteed to have it covered, however it's the part about a div with no height that holds a bunch of elements above and below it that's not giving me rest. Is this good practice and if not how else could I do this?

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. In terms of code though I see no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Set a `min-height` and a `min-width` the size of the actual rendered date picker. That way you have a little wiggle room in case the client's browser renders larger than yours and you don't have to worry about potentially collapsed divs.

The absolute elements will go where you tell them, explicitly, relative to it's relative container.

The wrapper is what I mean should have the minimums set, because nowhere in your CSS is a width or height mentioned.

Really, the area you click to load the date picker should be relative, the first item (a wrapper for your GUI/date picker) should be absolute, then all elements *inside* that should be relative (or static, but not absolute). That way your absolute container does have content inside it, as absolute containers are **outside the flow of normal (static/relative) content**, similar to floats.

If your title winds up being 100px in  height, and your datepicker 200px in height, while your wrapper is only 250px in height, 50px will go into limbo (overlap, since ones `top:0` and the other `bottom:0`)

So to recap.. **relative < absolute < relative (or static) + relative (or static)**, and I would still set a min-width/min-height on the absolute layer. Try zooming way in with the datepicker showing (Control and +) to see if it has any issues. If it goes all the way zoomed with no issues, you might be alright.

Comment: By `the actual rendered date picker` do you mean the `wrapper` or the elements inside it ( the visible ones ) ?

Comment: I mean width/height of everything that the user (you) see when the date picker loads. (ie, 200x150, 300x240). You can use Firefox's box model option in the developers tools to see what size it's currently rendering at.

Comment: Oh well I've done that. I was wondering about `wrapper` not having height but still holding elements.. It's that thing when you hover over that div in the HTML inspector and you see no markings on the document, but it actually holds stuff, you know something's not right..